# XSD ordering for extended type?

Tags: xsd, schema

I am trying to write a schema that doesn't require specific ordering for an extended type.  I tried to use an "all" group, but it seems to only permit a "sequence".

I am getting this error message and am a bit confused.

> An all model group must appear in a particle with {min occurs} = {max occurs} = 1, and that particle must be part of a pair which constitutes the {content type} of a complex type definition.

```
    <complexType name="credentialElement">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="env:namedElement">
            <all>
                <element name="username" type="env:envString" minOccurs="1" />
                <element name="password" type="env:envString" minOccurs="1" />
                <element name="domain" type="env:envString" minOccurs="0" />
            </all>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

Eric

EDIT:
It seems that this is not possible.  After running this through xmlint I got a different error message:

> The type has an 'all' model group in its {content type} and thus cannot be derived from a non-empty type, since this would produce a 'sequence' model group containing the 'all' model group; 'all' model groups are not allowed to appear inside other model groups.

Not sure if there is a clean work around.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about order. Use a `<sequence/>`. It's simpler, less ambiguous, better supported by tools - and most people entering XML by hand (and thus interested in order) can use a schema-enabled editor, so will know what comes next.